# What is the industrial yield of paracetamol?

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry, drugs, pharmacology

Anyone know how I can find out the typical yield of paracetamol (acetaminophen) from the acetylation of 4-aminophenol?

Please provide the source if you happen to know!

Comment: It depends upon the route which of the two are you interested in?

Comment: @user1945827 acetylation using anhydride from 4-aminophenol

Comment: Details should be in here, http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/op960007u

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a variety of explanations of industrial techniques as applied to acetylation,  including acetaminophen synthesis,  try here
https://www.google.com/patents/US20120065423
The examples are right at the bottom and are only scaled down lab versions of the industrial technique. Over 90% yield should be easily achievable if acetic anhydride is used (and is achieved in the industrial synthesis of ibuprofen).  The patent examples give yields for the use of acetic anhydride and acetic acid, as well as the technology employed e.g. continuous stirred tank reactor (cstr)  vs plug flow reactor (pfr or tubular reactor)  vs reactive distillation.  Enjoy.